# RoR: Instagram API: Pagination doesn't show up in JSON? Missing media also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, instagram

I have output some JSON, but i'm missing pagination information?

I'm looking for pagination because I have a count number of photos I want to display, but it doesn't display the number I want.

This is in my controller :

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
@user = client.user
@recent_media_items = client.user_recent_media

@tag_media_items = client.tag_recent_media('cat', options = {:count => 60})

@location_media_items = client.location_recent_media('12345', options = {:count => 60})
```

In in my views I have this:

```
<% (@tag_media_items+@location_media_items).sort{|a,b| -(a.created_time <=> b.created_time)}.each do |media| %>
    <span>
    <img src="<%= media.images.thumbnail.url %>">
    </span>
<% end %>
```

This pretty much puts these two media into an array and sorts it by created_time. But when it outputs, I only get a total of 42 images, not 120. I looked in instagram and the images match the search I tested, but it also has many more pictures!

Is the additional images in the pagination which I can't see?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Instagram API still doesn't offer pagination for media search (geo) queries.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/aLanTqk3LnY

and

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/instagram-api-developers/pagination/instagram-api-developers/qY_dqCPj-k8/y4u7y4sF1GQJ

:(